# puppet-mongodb module doesn't show Mongo shell errors in puppet-agent run

Tags: ruby, mongodb, puppet

We use the [voxpupuli/puppet-mongodb](https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-mongodb) module to create and manage Mongo data bases and users.
As usual we add necessary data to manifests and Hiera and after that the module form a command which it runs on the client side during a puppet-agent run.
We can see the executing command from the puppet-agent debug logs for instance this command create a new DB with the name unixtest_db:

```
Executing: '/usr/bin/mongo unixtest_db2 --quiet --host 127.0.0.1:27017 --eval load('/root/.mongorc.js'); db.dummyData.insert({"created_by_puppet": 1})'
```

The problem is the module never report any errors occurred during the commands execution.

For example consider the next hiera code:

```
tele2_mongodb::mongodb_db:
  'unixtest_db':  # DB name
    user     : unixtest
    password : >
      ENC[PKCS7,....]
    auth_mechanism : scram_sha_1
    roles    :
      - dbOwner
```

As result we have the next command executing and results:

```
Executing: '/usr/bin/mongo unixtest_db2 --quiet --host 127.0.0.1:27017 --eval load('/root/.mongorc.js'); db.dummyData.insert({"created_by_puppet": 1})' 
Notice: /Stage[main]/Tele2_mongodb/Mongodb::Db[unixtest_db]/Mongodb_database[unixtest_db]/ensure: created
```

Now we can connect to the DB with the user credential mentioned in hiera:

```
# mongo -u unixtest -p password unixtest_db 
MongoDB shell version v5.0.9 connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/unixtest_db? 
... 
unixtesttst:PRIMARY>
```

Next we change the DB name in Hiera to all capital letters:

```
tele2_mongodb::mongodb_db:
  'UNIXTEST_DB':  # DB name
```

In puppet agent output we see identical:

```
Executing: '/usr/bin/mongo UNIXTEST_DB --quiet --host 127.0.0.1:27017 --eval load('/root/.mongorc.js'); db.dummyData.insert({"created_by_puppet": 1})' 
Notice: /Stage[main]/Tele2_mongodb/Mongodb::Db[UNIXTEST_DB]/Mongodb_database[UNIXTEST_DB]/ensure: created
```

But the database is not created, it's not in the `db.adminCommand('listDatabases')` output (the 1st one with all small letters still exist).

And if we run the command manually on the OS console, we see the error message:

```
# /usr/bin/mongo UNIXTEST_DB  --host 127.0.0.1:27017 --eval " load('/root/.mongorc.js'); db.dummyData.insert({"created_by_puppet": 1})"
MongoDB shell version v5.0.9
...
WriteResult({
        "nInserted" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 13297,
                "errmsg" : "db already exists with different case already have: [unixtest_db] trying to create [UNIXTEST_DB]"
        }
})
```

So my question is how to make the puppet also report errors if command execution failed instead of fake notification everything went smoothly.

I have the same problem for DB changes, users and passwords. If something went wrong we never know that from the puppet output.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: This isn't an issue with Puppet itself, but rather one with the third-party module you are using.  Unless you're interested in hacking the module yourself, your best bet is to file a ticket against it.

Comment: Yes, I agree, I just tried my luck if someone saw the same before.